# How was Terry Colby framed in Mr. Robot Episode 1?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In the First Episode Terry Colby is framed for hacking into the server.
All Elliot did was replace the log in the DVD/CD/Disc.

There would be ISP logs both for the server and Colby's IP:

- First logs of Colby's ISP will be looked into.
- Then the logs for the server and it's ISP.

Would one be considered guilty just based on an IP in a DVD/CD/Disc?

Is this a logical flaw in the show?

Comment: A good question that belongs on a computer/law forum, not the Movies & TV Stack Exchange. Let us know what you find out!

Answer (score 3):

No.

IP is not a hard evidence to frame someone.

You know, PCs all over the world change IP dynamically and too often, tracking someone isn't impossible, but you have to target him and watch his moves, closely.
Due to the architecture of internet, when someone connects to a server, this request hoping around nodes all over the world to reach its destination.

SO the KEY

Due to signal hoping and proxy connections (faking client's ip with someone's in the middle), you can refuse to admit that you did anything, 

you can just pretend that you are innocent, you know nothing and give the impression that YOU are the first who has been hacked(hackers used your PC as a proxy).


BUT 
Terry Colby had a significant position at a corporation that knows how to use internet technologies, so Colby couldn't use excuses like that.

Comment: I'm talking about why they wouldn't look at ISP logs and other logs and only look at logs given in a DVD by someone with mental disorders